# Is there a document discussing the structure of the vim sourcecode?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm interesting in working on the Vim codebase but it I can't find any overall structural documentation.  Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Download the source code, read it, ask question on the mailing list.

Comment: I find this an excellent question! Wondering why anyone would vote it down. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of documentation, there is very little; `:help development` gives some general introduction, but you mostly just have to dive into the source code, jump around (easy with ctags support).

The todo list (`:help todo`; updated version in the Mercurial repository) contains (way too) many items, both small and large. Pick some little thing and try to solve it. Any help and contribution is most welcome! I recommend to join the vim_dev mailing list, as you send your patches there and can ask questions about the source code.